# How to change the color of my hostname in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to modify the color of some parts of my prompt, I would like that it displays the color of my username in Cyan which I searched that it matchs with \u then I would like to display the color of my hostname in purple which matchs with \h, in order to achieve this when I type:

```
echo $PS1
```

I get:

```
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

then I tried:

```
export PS1="\e[0;36m\e[0;35m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "
```

But I failed since it just colors everything of Purple, 
I would like to know how to achieve why is not coloring the hostname, the color's list is the following:

```
Color   Code
Black   0;30
Blue    0;34
Green   0;32
Cyan    0;36
Red     0;31
Purple  0;35
Brown   0;33
Blue    0;34
Green   0;32
Cyan    0;36
Red     0;31
Purple  0;35
Brown   0;33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset each colour change via `\e[0m`.

Use `\[...\]` around invisible parts of the prompt, otherwise history navigation will get confused about the line length:

```
PS1="[\[\e[0;35m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[0;36m\]\h\[\e[0m\] \W]\$ "
```

Comment: thanks this was really helpful, I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
export PS1="[\e[0;36m\u@\e[0;35m\h \e[0;30m\W]\$"
```

This should give cyan to username and purple to hostname and black after that.

Comment: I appreciate the support.

Comment: but I am having some problems since this also changed the color of the letters of my terminal to black

Comment: Use `\[\e[0m\]` at end to revert to default color

Answer (score 1):

Escapes must be between `\[` and `\]` inside your $PS1. Otherwise they will be printed verbatim.

```
export PS1='\[\e[0;36m\e[0;35m[\]\u@\h \W]\$ \[\e[0m\] '
```

The `\[\e[0m\]` at the end means "reset back to default color."

Also, you may want to consider single-quoted strings because inside them a `\` always means `\`; this makes it easier to see what you're doing.